# AngularJS: How to make the initialization of view wait until we get the response from the service?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

We have an AngularJS app where we have multiple states, which are defined with **ui-router**. In one of those states, we need to wait for HTML Initialization until the service responses.

Normally we design our application so that all the service calls run asynchronously, and the views show a loading spinner on the relevant positions. But on this state, we really should/can not show anything to user until the service responses.

How can i define this state, so that it initializes the view only then after the service response?

Our state and component definitions are quite simple:

```
.state(STATES.details,
  {
    url: "/?ref",
    template: '<app-details></app-details>',
  })
```

...

```
.component('details', {
    controller: 'DetailsController as detailsController',
    templateUrl: 'module/details.html'
  }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `resolve` https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve for that case:

> If any of these dependencies are promises, they will be resolved and converted to a value before the controller is instantiated and the $stateChangeSuccess event is fired.

```
.state(STATES.details,
{
    url: "/?ref",
    component: 'details', // The component's name

    resolve:{

     // Example using function with returned promise.
     // This is the typical use case of resolve.
     // You need to inject any services that you are
     // using, e.g. $http in this example
     promiseObj:  function($http){
        // $http returns a promise for the url data
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'});
     }

})
```

Comment: Thank you. But i still have some problems reading the value.. i defined the promiseObj as dependency and i get "[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider" from my controller while initializing

Comment: For component routing check here: [https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component#update-the-state-definition](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component#update-the-state-definition). You will need to replace `template` with `component`

Comment: thank you again.. But for the others reading this answer: either use "component in state definition, and bindings in component definition" or "use controller definition in state definition and dependency injection in controller".  When you mix those, does not work at all..

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at using resolve. It can do what you need which will wait for a promise (or multiple)i to finish before loading: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve